# How I can set a limit for collecting gold in my monogame?

Tags: c#, counter, limit, monogame

I want to limit my Goldmine in my C# monogame. I want that there are 10 gold and after collecting them there is new gold. Every 5 seconds 2 new gold. This works perfect in my code. But now I want that there is a limit after waiting for gold. If the player waits for a very long time, he should only get 10 gold.
But the limit is not working.
Are there any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
public static void CollectGold(ObjectFactory.ObjectType type)
{
    if(MaxGoldLimit <=10)
    { 
        if (sMaxGold > 0)
        {
            Hud.mGold += 2;
            sMaxGold -= 2;
        }
        if (Hud.mCurrentTime >= Hud.mCountDuration)
        {
            Counter++;
            Hud.mCurrentTime -= Hud.mCountDuration
            if (sMaxGold < 10)
            { 
                sMaxGold += 2;
            }
            if (sMaxGold >= 10)
            {
                sMaxGold -= 2;  // or sMaxGold = 10 in earlier version-> same output 
            }
         }
    }                   
}
```

sMaxGold is my limit. This should never be over 10. But every 5 seconds I get 2 new gold. So the limit isn't working.
Is there anyone who could help me?

edit:

I build my objects in an object factory.

```
case ObjectFactory.ObjectType.GoldVein:
    mActiveButtons.Add(ObjectFactory.ObjectType.GoldVein.ToString());
    mButtons[ObjectFactory.ObjectType.GoldVein.ToString()].SetLocation(one);
    mButtons[ObjectFactory.ObjectType.GoldVein.ToString()].mAction = 
    GoldVein.CollectGold;
    mButtons[ObjectFactory.ObjectType.GoldVein.ToString()].UpdateText("Collect");
    MAXGoldLimit= 10;
    break;
```

and this is how i draw the mine with my object manager:

```
CreateObject(ObjectFactory.ObjectType.GoldVein, new Point(TileSize * 26, TileSize * 8);
CreateObject(ObjectFactory.ObjectType.GoldVein, new Point(TileSize * 30, TileSize * 8);
```

Comment: You seem to be missing one closing curly brace.

Comment: oh yes, thank you. But only here. In my code there is the brace. So that wasn't the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding **Else** in the Statement

```
 public static void CollectGold(ObjectFactory.ObjectType type)
 { 

  if (Hud.mCurrentTime >= Hud.mCountDuration)
  {
       Counter++;
       Hud.mCurrentTime -= Hud.mCountDuration
       if (sMaxGold < 10)
       { 
        sMaxGold += 2;
       }
       if (sMaxGold >= 10)
       {
           sMaxGold -= 2;  // or sMaxGold = 10 in earlier version-> same output 
       }
  }
  else if (sMaxGold > 0)
  {
         Hud.mGold += 2;
         sMaxGold -= 2;
  }

 }
```

Comment: Now I added a second mine, but this method works now for both together. How can I seperate it? That this method works for both goldmines but independent.

Comment: You can Add MAXGoldLimit in every Hud Object and give it limit. Also you can gave different limit to each Hud if you want to. **In my Opinion add GoldLimit to Every Hud Object.**

Comment: But I use an object factory, so I only can give a limit to both. I editet the code above to show you how I implemented my hud.